# functional calculus and spectral measure

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $T$ be a normal operator and $f$ be a bounded borel function on ${\sigma}(T)$. If $E_{T}$ and $E_{f(T)}$ are the spectral decompositions of $T$ and $f(T)$ respectively, prove that for any borel set $w$ we have that $E_{f(T)}(w)=E_{T}(f^{-1}(w))$ for any borel subset $w$ of ${\sigma}(T)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that, at the function level, you have
$$
1_w\circ f=1_{f^{-1}(w)}.
$$
So, using functional calculus, 
$$
E_{f(T)}(w)=1_w(f(T))=1_w\circ f(T)=1_{f^{-1}(W)}(T)=E_T(f^{-1}(w)).
$$

Comment: The equality $E_{f(T)}(w)=1_w(f(T))$ is not clear to me ( I assume $1_{w}$ is the indicator function). Indeed the spectral measure does not take only the values 0 and 1 so maybe I have mistaken notation @Martin Argerami

Comment: For any operator $R$, $$1_w(R)=\int_{\sigma(R)}1_w(\lambda)\,dE_R(\lambda)=E_R(w). $$

Comment: assuming that $1_{w}$ is the function sending elements of $w$  to 1 and is otherwise 0, what is the meaning of $1_{w}(R)$? I must be misunderstanding your notation $1_{w}$. @MartinArgerami

Comment: The meaning is exactly the first equality in my last comment.  If that is not clear, what do you mean when you say "$f(T) $"?

Comment: Ah I see you are using it as an '$f$'. Apologies for the misunderstanding.

Comment: No worries. I get confused with much easier things.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $f(T)$ is
$$
         f(T) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(\lambda)dE(\lambda),
$$
for any bounded Borel function $f$ on $\sigma(T)$. For convenience, extend $f$ to be $0$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\sigma(T)$, and suppose $f$ is strictly bounded by $M$. Then $\Re f$ and $\Im f$ are strictly bounded by $M$. Let $N$ be a positive integer, and divide the rectangle $\{ \lambda \in\mathbb{C} : -M \le \Re f < M,\;-M \le \Im f < M\}$ into $N^{2}$ equal squares $S_{j,k}$ (closed on the left and bottom, open on the right and top) with centers $c_{j,k}$ for $1 \le j,k \le N$. Then
$$
              f(\lambda) - \sum_{j,k}c_{j,k}\chi_{f^{-1}(S_{j,k})}(\lambda)
$$
is uniformly bounded by $M/N$ on $\mathbb{C}$. Therefore, integrating with respect to $E$ gives
$$
                       \left\|f(T)-\sum_{j,k}c_{j,k}E(f^{-1}(S_{j,k}))\right\| \le M/N.
$$
Define $E_{f}(S)=E(f^{-1}(S))$. Then $E_{f}$ is a spectral measure, and the above implies
$$
                f(T)=\lim_{N}\sum_{j,k}c_{j,k}E_{f}(S_{j,k}).
$$
Notice also that
$$
   \left\|\sum_{j,k}c_{j,k}E_{f}(S_{j,k})-\int \lambda dE_{f}(\lambda)\right\| \le M/N
$$
Therefore,
$$
                  f(T)= \int f(\lambda)dE(\lambda)=\int \lambda dE_{f}(\lambda).
$$
By uniqueness of spectral measures $E_{f}$ is the spectral measure for $f(T)$. That is, $E_{T}(f^{-1}(S))=E_{f(T)}(S)$.